# Android three items next to each other

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a layout for my recyclerview with three items next to each other horizontally.

I was hoping to achieve this with a LinearLayout but the last item (the ImageButton) won't appear. I've been trying combination of weights as well.

Is there a good way to achieve this? The following is my current layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_option"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/option"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_option"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:lines="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_minus"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` your `editText` is covering all the space

Comment: @AbdulKawee it is true that when I put a small value in it. the ImageButton appears. But that wouldn't be the best practice to set a fixed small value. It should dymanically take all space available

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: if you want equal widths for all three views. Use width = match_parent for all views and asign them equal weight of 1 and assign weight sum  3 to parent Linear Layout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just give EditText weight

So try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/option"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_option"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:lines="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_minus"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace it with below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_option"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="option"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_option"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_minus" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to go with a ConstraintLayout and use chains. It look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_option"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/option"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="editText_option"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStarOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_option"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:lines="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="textView_option"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonOption"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  />

<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButtonOption"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_minus"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView_option"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

 />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can then change the style of the chains with the chainStyle attribute.